# How to find select conversion failed value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query from core of data which is nvarchar and all values are '00:00:00' format. I want to convert it into long. When I try to convert top 1000 it working fine but problem with all values. Query show in below

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', CAST(TimeSpent AS time(7)))* cast(1000 as bigint) + RIGHT(CAST(TimeSpent AS time(7)),7) FROM [mtr].[MatterDocument]
```

The error statement is

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string**

How can I find which value failed to convert?

Comment: Please tag your database system (sql server, Oracle etc etc)

Comment: @HoneyBadger now check

Comment: What is the type conversion error that you get?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What is your server's version? select @@version

Comment: I propose that you edit your post in order to include the error message in the question, as this is vital information of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, Azure Sql Server

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Azure Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that there is some bad data in your `MatterDocument` table.  SQL Server does not support regex searches, but fortunately its `LIKE` operator does support some primitive regex which we can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM [mtr].[MatterDocument]
WHERE TimeSpent NOT LIKE '[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' AND
      TimeSpent NOT LIKE '2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]';
```

### Demo

You may verify in the demo that bad, non acceptable, time strings are being flushed out.  The above query should also work to flush out strings which maybe aren't even time values at all, and somehow made it into your table.

The best long term fix would be to correct your data at its source, and then bring the data into SQL Server as a bona fide date/time type.

Edit: `TRY_CAST`, as described by @Denis in his answer, might be another approach.  But this would require SQL Server 2012 or later.  The above query should still work in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for help. You are right. Unfortunately some data were inserted. That's why its failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to find the wrong rows (it returns NULL if it cannot convert the value)

```
SELECT c.TimeSpent, /*Any columns to identify rows */
FROM (
SELECT TimeSpent, /*Any columns to identify rows */ 
DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', TRY_CAST(TimeSpent AS time(7)))* cast(1000 as bigint)
 + RIGHT(TRY_CAST(TimeSpent AS time(7)),7) AS Converted
FROM [mtr].[MatterDocument]
) c
WHERE Converted IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find the bad values:

```
select timespent
from t
where try_cast(TimeSpent AS time(7)) is null;
```

This will enable you to find the bad values.  They are probably times that exceed 23.

I would suggest doing the conversion more simply:

```
select (left(TimeSpent, 2) * 60 * 60 + 
        substring(TimeStpent, 4, 2) * 60 +
        right(TimeSpent, 2)
       ) as seconds
```

This will do the conversion without the limitations of the SQL Server `time` data type.